# Python 3 combining file open and read commands - a need to close a file and how?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working through "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way" and am making code more concise. Lines 11 to 18 of the program below (line 1 starts at # program: p17.py) are relevant to my question. Opening and reading a file are very easy and it is easy to see how you close the file you open when working with the files. The original section is commented out and I include the concise code on line 16. I commented out the line of code that causes an error (on line 20):

$ python3 p17_aside.py p17_text.txt p17_to_file_3.py
Copying from p17_text.txt to p17_to_file_3.py
This is text.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p17_aside.py", line 20, in 
    indata.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

---

Code is below:

---

```
# program: p17.py
# This program copies one file to another. It uses the argv function as well
# as exists - from sys and os.path modules respectively
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print(f"Copying from {from_file} to {to_file}")

# we could do these two on one line, how?
#in_file = open(from_file)
#indata = in_file.read()
#print(indata)
# THE ANSWER -
indata = open(from_file).read()
# The next line was used for testing
print(indata)

# indata.close()
```

---

So my question is should I just avoid the practice of combining commands as done above or is there a way to properly deal with that situation so files are closed when they should be? Is it necessary to deal with the situation of closing a file at all in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

[Context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-context-manager) and [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement is a comfortable way to make sure your file is closed as needed:

```
with open(from_file) as fobj:
    indata = fobj.read()
```

Nowadays, you can also use Path-like objects and their [`read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) and [`read_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_bytes) methods:

```
# This assumes Path from pathlib has been imported
indata = Path(from_file).read_text()
```

The error you were seeing... is because you were not trying to close the file, but `str` into which you've read its content into. You'd need to assign object returned by open a name, and then read from and close that one:

```
fobj = open(from_file)
indata = fobj.read()
fobj.close()  # This is OK
```

Strictly speaking, you would not need to close that file as dangling file descriptors would be "clobbered" with the process. Esp. in a short example like this, it would be of relatively little concern.

---

I hope I got the follow up question in comment correctly to extend on this a bit more.

If you wanted a single command, look at the `pathtlib.Path` example above.

With `open` as such, you cannot perform `read` and `close` in a single operation and without assigning result of `open` to a variable. As both `read` and `close` would have to be performed on the same object returned by `open`. If you do:

```
var = fobj.read()
```

Now, `var` refers to content read out of the file (so nothing that you could close, would have a `close` method).

If you did:

```
open(from_file).close()
```

After (but also before; at any point), you would simply open that file (again) and close it immediately. BTW. this returns `None`, just in case you wanted to get the return value. But it would not affect previously open file handles and file-like objects. It would not serve any practical purpose except for perhaps making sure you can open a file.

But again. It's a good practice to perform the housekeeping, but strictly speaking (and esp. in a short code like this). If you did not close the file and relied on the OS to clean-up after your process. It'd work fine.

Comment: How about the following:
    # to open the file and read it
    indata = open(from_file).read()
    print(indata)
    # this closes the file - just the opposite of opening and reading
    open(from_file).close()

Answer (score -1):

How about the following:
    # to open the file and read it
    indata = open(from_file).read()
    print(indata)
    # this closes the file - just the opposite of opening and reading
    open(from_file).close()